# How to properly redirect after insert with Knex in expressjs

Tags: node.js, database, express

I have been trying to redirect after inserting into DB
The data is inserted correctly but re-direction is not working properly.
I don't know what I am doing wrong

Once the data is inserted successfully, redirect to index and update the list with the new data

```
exports.addbooks = function (req, res)
{
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        bookname: Joi.string().trim().min(6).max(25).required(),
        summaries: Joi.string().trim().required(),
        isbn: Joi.number().required(),
        categories: Joi.string().trim().required(),

    });
    Joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect("/");
        }

        url = (slug(req.body.categories));
        //I have to get the auth user and add to the field later
        //Perform knex insert into db
        author = "1";
        knex('book').insert({
            book_name: req.body.bookname,
            author: author,
            summary: req.body.summaries,
            isbn: req.body.isbn,
            category: req.body.categories,
            url: url
        }).then(function(result){
            res.render('index', {result});
            knex.destroy();
        })
    })
}
```

You can see that if validation is unsuccessful then redirect back to index
But if validation is ok and inserts occurred the redirect back to the index and show the latest result
But something is not right here
I am to Nodejs. I am trying to use my Laravel Idea

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should `return` from your function immediately after you `redirect` otherwise the rest of the code in the function is going to be called.  So: `return res.redirect("/");`.  Also please elaborate on what you mean by "not working properly".

Comment: What I mean is that after clicking the submit button, the page is not redirected back to the index. rather shows a blank index page with no data. I am expecting a redirect back to index showing list of the item already in the DB with the newly inserted data. Also, where should I put `return res.redirect("/");` Because I replaced ` res.render('index', {result});' but not getting the desired result